# Delete Padding top in a TextView inside a Horizontal StackView

Tags: ios, swift, textview, storyboard, uistackview

I want to delete padding top from a TextView inside a Horizontal StackView
[image]

I’ve read a lot about it on apple developer docs and stackoverflow and had tried for example:

```
logoTextView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
```

but that no has a effect that I need. How can I delete that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a work around to fix your problem.
Go to your UITextView -> File Inspector -> Select Text as Attributed (instead of Plain) -> change the line max Height. Below is the screenshot for the same. It might resolve your problem.

[image]